# MVC3 Hidden for value not persisting between form postback

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3

I have a question, I have value as below which I set in an action method and the hidden value is available in the view. Now when I post a form to an action method, the hidden field value is gone. Any ideas on this?

```
   @using (Html.BeginForm("Create", "RunLogEntry", FormMethod.Post, new { enctype = "multipart/form-data" }))
        {

        @Html.HiddenFor(model => Model.OutputStoredFileName)

        <button name="submit" class="art-button" type="submit" value="Populate" style="width: 100px">
                Attach</button>
    }


 [HttpPost]
public ActionResult Create(RunLogEntry runLogEntry, String ServiceRequest, string Hour, string Minute, string AMPM,string submit, IEnumerable<HttpPostedFileBase> file, String AssayPerformanceIssues1)
        {
        if(submit == "Populate")
         {
               //Runlogentry is the model
               if ((System.IO.File.Exists(runLogEntry.OutputStoredFileName)))
                            System.IO.File.Delete(runLogEntry.LoadListStoredFileName);
```

Comment: How are you receiving the value? Post (pun intended) your controller action that is receiving the value...

Comment: Updated the code, I have a button which hits the action method

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try replacing

`@Html.HiddenFor(model => Model.OutputStoredFileName)`

with

`@Html.HiddenFor(model => model.OutputStoredFileName)`

Confirm in FireBug or Fiddler that the value is posted to the server in the request.

Comment: found solution. My page is a bit tricky. I had to do this in the controller action method before i saved it. ModelState.Remove("LoadListStoredFileName");.  That took care of it and now i can easily value the correct value